# Creation of Release Build Failed in UWP

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

I am trying to build a UWP project in Release. But i am not able to create the build and I am getting an error  **could not copy the file "C:\Users\kumara krishnan\.nuget\packages\System.Private.Uri\4.0.0\runtimes\win8-aot\lib\netcore50\System.Private.Uri.dll" because it was not found.** Also I am able to build and deploy when i keep it in debug mode. How to fix this issue?

Comment: close visual studio 2015 and go to the project's folder.  Delete the obj folder open visual studio and try again

Comment: Tried that. Still facing this issue.

Comment: There is no obvious reason why this file would go missing.  At least have a look to see if it is there.  Then check that Nuget is operating correctly.  And disable anti-malware and try again.

Comment: The file is not present in the mentioned folder. What do i do now??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is something wrong with your .nuget environment. You can try following steps to fix it.

Firstly delete the whole **`System.Private.Uri`** folder under **`C:\Users\kumara krishnan\.nuget\packages\`**.

Then in Visual Studio, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the "NuGet Package Manager" node and make sure you have checked "Allow NuGet to download missing packages" and "Automatically check for missing package during build in Visual Studio".
[image]

After this, you can just rebuild your project and Visual Studio will automatically restore the NuGet packages your project used and download whole "System.Private.Uri" files.

You can also create a blank app and create a new instance of `Uri` without adding other references manually to check your environment.

Comment: I tried this. The .nuget dir was created and the system.private.uri.dll is also present now. But i am getting invalid type in resx file error and few more file not found errors... Should I reinstall visual studio...

Comment: @Kumara: If you still have file not found errors like System.Private.Uri.dll, you can try to delete all packages in **`C:\Users\kumara krishnan\.nuget\ `** and let Visual Studio restore them. After this, if you still have errors, you may try to reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: Yeah i did just the same... Seems like i have to reinstall visual studio :(

Comment: I repaired Visual Studio. Now I'm able to get a release build :)